# what is the meaning of "like a stick of rock" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Mum had been on the phone, wanting to know when we would be back from
> holiday, so that the children would do her online order for a new
> senior railcard, and I would be able to referee her current dispute
> with the Royal Albert Hall, and my husband would design and build a
> reflective panel to sit behind one of her radiators, the better to
> direct more heat into her already sweltering kitchen. I explained this
> to Maureen, who rubbed a glass with a cloth and said comfortably,
> ‘Well, my children say to me, “Mother, we will not hear you say a bad
> word about Nanna, because, sure, she’s the way you are going.” ’
>
> Steady on, Maureen! You haven’t met my mum! But her words – or rather
> her children’s words – stayed with me. I have to think about my mum
> and the things she does that I love, and the things she does that I
> really don’t love. I recognize patterns that run through us both like
> a stick of rock, and it’s not a comfortable process.

I found "a stick of rock" is a kind of candy. But it doesn't help me to understand the last sentence of this text. Is there any other meaning?

Answer (score 4):

You are right in saying that "rock" here refers to the confectionery. From [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_(confectionery)): "These cylinders usually have a pattern embedded throughout the length, which is often the name of the resort where the rock is sold, so that the name can be read on both ends of the stick (reversed at one end) and remains legible even after pieces are bitten off." This is a distinctive, notable feature of sticks of rock.

Comment: Usually sold at seaside resorts, but [other places too](https://store.liverpoolfc.com/liverpool-fc-rock).

Answer (score 0):

The answers from Michael Harvey and Rosie both explain that "seaside rock" in the UK is a sweet confection (usually flavoured with mint but often with fruit extract) which traditionally has the name of the resort written all the way through it (I could explain how but it would take too long). This means that wherever the rock is cut across the word is (more or less) legible in the cross section.

The point is that it is common in the UK to describe a person's deeply embedded emotional characteristic or commitment to an organisation or cause which has become a defining characteristic of that person as being "written through them like a stick of rock".

An example would be an employee of a company (Acme PLC for example) who has a more than usually high level of commitment to the company, particularly if that commitment makes him resistant to criticism of local management, might be described by fellow workers as "Tom's's got 'Acme PLC' written through him like a stick of rock". This expresses the idea that the commitment is inherent to Tom's being, self identity and sense of purpose. If Acme closed down the warehouse where Tom worked he wouldn't just be out of a job, his whole world would collapse.

The idea that someone has something "written through them like a stick of rock" is very rarely positive, it usually expresses obsession or, as in the quoted piece, something which causes the person to do things against their own interest.

As an aside (and nothing to with something "being written through someone like stick of rock") Pinkie, the central character in Graham Greene's novel "Brighton Rock", leads a gang who use large sticks of Brighton rock (rock with 'Brighton' written through it) as weapons of assault and murder. The idea that a light-hearted confection could be used as an unidentifiable weapon makes Brighton Rock as a novel particularly shocking.

Comment: 'The idea that someone has something "written through them like a stick of rock" is very rarely positive' - I think you could say that a deeply honest person has 'integrity' written through them like in a stick of rock.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I didn't say never, Michael, just rarely. In my experience it's usually negative, at least from the point of view of person uttering the phrase.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a picture of one end of a stick of rock sold in the UK seaside resort of Blackpool.

[image]

Comment: I'm fairly sure the quote in the question isn't a reference to anyone's penis.

Comment: @StuartF - I'm sure that you are right.

Comment: @StuartF - This pair of comments is beautifully out of context. Please don't explain.